# Using an if statement and a int.tryparse to loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to use an if statement and a int.tryparse to try and create a loop that keeps running until a proper integer is given. A friend of mine said it could be done using an the pieces I mentioned above. Yet I have my doubts, was wondering if anyone could either verify this works or help me figure it out.

so far I have

```
if (!int.TryParse(temp, out move)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bad integer")
}
```

Looking at this I don't see how it would loop, I was thinking a while loop might work better but am at a loss as to how I would set one up.

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

Comment: Keeps running until a proper integer is given? By user?

Comment: what about this `string temp = null; do{ if(temp != null)Console.WriteLine("Bad integer");  temp = Console.Readkey(); }while(int.TryParse(temp, out move);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless that's *within* a loop of some sort, continuously asking for a new `temp` value, it *won't* loop back for more.

The sort of thing you're looking for is:

```
temp = Console.ReadLine();
while (!Int32.TryParse(temp, out move))  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bad integer");
    temp = Console.ReadLine();
}
// move should be okay now.
```

though there's a lot you can do to improve, handling exceptions and so on.

Comment: Just for clarification, the while(!int.TryParse(temp, out move)) means that while int.TryParse fails (or returns false/null?), keep looping through?

Comment: @Jeff, yes. `TryParse` returns true if all is okay, so false means something went wrong. Using `!` will invert that return value. In English, `while didn't fail parsing`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Simply using the `int.TryParse` won't make a loop.  You will have to write it in a `while` loop as below -

```
while( //your condition)
{
  if (!int.TryParse(temp, out move)) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bad integer")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int move;

Console.Write("Enter int: ");
var temp = Console.ReadLine();

while (!int.TryParse(temp, out move))
{
    Console.Write("Enter int: ");
    temp = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    int j;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out j))
    {
        Console.Write("Bad integer\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int corectinteger;
int input = Console.ReadLine();
bool flag = true;
while (flag)
{
    if (input != corectinteger)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bad integer");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (input == corectinteger)
        flag = false;
}
```